# Page factory initilization issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, page-factory

Does PageFactory.initElements(driver,this) try to initialize all element written in the page?

I have login page where only username and login button is there. once i enter username and hit login then password box comes in.

I have written username,password and Login button  findby method in LoginPage class.  Now before entering username and clicking on login button, i am trying to initilize the LoginPage. As the password field is not there will it throw error ?

Thanks,

Comment: Run it... what does it do? You need to update your question with more details. You should post the code that you have written and any error messages, etc. We can't guess based on your description. It's not clear what you are doing without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after doing lots of googling and debugging my page factory code initialization.

When we try to initialize the page using pagefactory init element it creates the proxy of each element and when we call webelement to do some actions on it like element.click() then it try to find the element in the page where you are right now.

One good post i found is at:
https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/09/05/understanding-pagefactory/